# Scrolling on WebApp with jQuery Mobile + PhoneGap on Android is bucking (suddenly stopping) - Choppy scroll

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

i have an issue when scrolling vertical within my app. Actually i'm having a jqm-panel and eventlisteners for swipeleft and swiperight events on my page (see below)...

```
$('#ccm_content').on('swiperight', function () {
    if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
        $('#menupanel').panel('open');
    }
});

$('ccm_content').on('swipeleft', function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest(".ui-slider").length) {
        return false;
    }
    //else{
        if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) === "open" ) {
            console.log("closing menupanel!");
            $('#menupanel').panel('close');
        }
    //}
});
```

Without those eventListeners, vertical scrolling is smooth - even when paning around with my thumb. 
In case i add those eventlisteners, scrolling is sometimes bucky and suddenly stops on a div or an anchor within the content.

I guess that's because i'm not scrolling at 100% on y-achsis all the time (but who really does?), and that schould not be the problem at all - but it actually is a problem.

Actually i like the JQM-panels and the swiping very much. But with this scrolling issue i probably have to discard them ore at least fall back to buttons.

Does anyone knows a workaround?
Maybe it helps wrapping the datarole="content" within a transparent div on scrollstart and remove the wrap on scrollstop.

-----**UPDATE**

Ok - so i've done some researching and i've found some pretty nice comments on a blog: look [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-jqm-touchscreen-list-scrolling-performance-stinks-and-what-to-do-about-it)!

I think i've got investigate some of my markup tomorrow.

There are several things which might be responsible for the choppy scroll in vertival direction (even though i'm using iScrollView which is btw veeeery cool. Have a look at those: [iScrollView](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) in combination with simultaneous transitions).

1. **`<a>` Tags:** Since my WebApp is not containing any listviews, but many `<div>`'s with `<img>` tags, which are wrapped inside an `<a>` tag, i think, it might be worth the time ro remove all the "bad?" anchors
2. **Shadows:** I like those nicy shadows provided by JQM but maybe i should have a try in boosting scroll-performance when diabling them - like suggested here: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286307/jquery-mobile-phonegap-vertical-scrolling-choppy-harder)
3. Fixed ToolBars

In order to distinguish between hScroll and vScroll maybe this will help me:

```
// you can set this fix in DOM ready or jQM's mobileinit

// DOM ready
$(function(){
$.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold = 100;
});



 // jQM defaults 
 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
     $.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold = 100; 
 });
```

If anything of these suggestions might bring me a bit closer to smoothy scrollness  - i'm gonna tell you.. at the latest tomorrow :-)

Kind regards,
TorchMan

-----**UPDATE**

Ok folks, bad news - nothing helped. I thought it has anything to do with those anchor-tags and they've been my most budding candidate.
What's next? I've experimented quite a while with iScroll but i've got to say that the `<ul>
  <li>
...
</li>
</ul>` Pattern is not what i wanted and iScroll only works good for listViews and not deep cascaded markup. The best way is to stay with iScrollView which wraps iScroll in a sophisticated way.
What i can tell 4 sure is, that markup consisting out of a pattern with DIV's and anchors and interlaced DIV's with IMG-Tags seem to result in a choppy scrolling (on Android webkit) - even with iScrollView.
Now i will change my dynamic markup to jQuery Mobile [ListViews](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/listviews/) coz i hope this will work. Btw the markup is not that deep interlaced and does not consist out of that much DIV-blocks.

Comment: `#ccm_content` is page or content div?

Comment: #ccm_content is the div with datarole="content". I've chosen ccm_content in order to not have swipeevent on the whole datarole="page" coz i'm having a flip-switch-toggle (class="ui-slider") within my panel.